# Mixed model with random factors and repeated measures

Tags: r

A question from a novice into statistics.

I want to perform a mixed model with person (ptid*) as random factor and with repeated measurements (point). position is a text which differs into 8 groups, why they are factorized. Using lmer i use this

```
model <- lmer (ai ~ factor(position) + (1|ptid) + (1|point), elfys)
```

the repeated measures = point are simply numbered from 1 to nmax and nmax vary from ptid to ptid. Does these numbers actually matter in the statistics (which I want to avoid). Since I have no interest in differences between the repeated measurements or any idea that there would be any temporal differences, i would assume it is a good idea also to include this as a random factor

Answer (score 1):

sorry I don't have the right o in your name.

You do not need to add the `+ (1|point)`.

stict to:

```
model <- lmer (ai ~ factor(position) + (1|ptid), elfys)
```

Maybe [this](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial2.pdf) is helpful to you.